# How to save result file of Gmapping? (through rviz)

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, build, gmapping-demo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to do tutorial : SLAM Map Building with Turtlebot.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM

My environments are ubuntu 11.10 and ROS electric.

My execution sequence is like this.

1. roslaunch turtlebot_bringup.minimal.launch (on the turtlebot)
2. roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch (on the turtlebot)
3. rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard& (on the workstation)
4. roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch (on the turtlebot)
5. roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch (on the workstation)
6. rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot_navigation`/nav_rviz.vcg (on the workstation)
7. rosrun map_server map_saver -f /tmp/my_map (on the turtlebot)

After do all sequence, I get rviz screen.

And then when i execute 7, I couldn't get map file (my_map.yaml)...

I don't know why.............

Help plz...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30937/how-to-save-result-file-of-gmapping?-(through-rviz)/) by [JamesJeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2098/jamesjeong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-04-01**:
Do you mean that you don't get ONLY .yaml file? Or both .yaml and image file? Also, just making sure, have you created /tmp folder ?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-04-01**:
Also, although I'm not sure exactly what phenomenon you're dealing with, I might have experienced similar situation. See http://answers.ros.org/question/11957/map_saver-doesnt-return-from-waiting-for-the-map

**Comment by [JamesJeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2098/jamesjeong/) on 2012-04-02**:
no... I couldn't get any files..... and when i execute 7, i  waited 5minutes more.... but console is not changed...

**Comment by [JamesJeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2098/jamesjeong/) on 2012-04-02**:
when i execute 7, i couldn't see " [INFO] [ros.time] : Waiting for the map" message... but i know that you already get this message. and you solve your problem through rebooting.. right? i did already trying that... but it's not solution in my case...

**Comment by [JamesJeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2098/jamesjeong/) on 2012-04-02**:
and i'm confirming connection between my workstation and turtlebot through command(rostopic list), dashboard, ping.... what should I do...?

**Comment by [JamesJeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2098/jamesjeong/) on 2012-04-02**:
When you had succeeded,  you would execute this command in this directory ("turtlebot@turtlebot-1:/tmp$ rosrun map_server map_saver -f /tmp/my_map" ) right? so i did same your case, too..... but fail......

**Comment by [JamesJeong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2098/jamesjeong/) on 2012-04-02**:
i get some message in console.. that message is this.         [ERROR] {1333382381.914160288]:  [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [192.168.0.67:11311].   Retrying... this case is that  i execute in tmp folder....

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-09**:
rostopic list doesn't confirm your connnection.  See the link from @fergs answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you setup both the turtlebot and the workstation to find each other?

(see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines for details)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0